# LTspice MOV tutorial/help

Tags: ltspice, component-selection, emi-filtering, mov, surge

I am looking at the availability of the pictured component on LTspice and cannot find it when I type it in the component library search. Please let me know the component symbol name or if I need to create the component from scratch (and how to if need be).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a SPICE model on the manufacturer's (TDK) [website](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/protection/voltage/lead-disk-varistor/info?part_no=B72214S0301K101).

You can import it, but it may or may not work with LTspice, as the models are written for PSPICE.

There are many well-constructed tutorials on the internet describing the process of incorporating 3rd party models in LTspice.